# How to get WebP images from gallery with PHPicker

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, phpickerviewcontroller, phpicker

I have a PHPIckerViewController which is available since iOS 14. And I want to get image from gallery which is format WEBP. But item provider in PHPicker can't load image with this format. Please tell me how can I pick and set image on UIButton with new picker.

code:

```
extension SixStepRegistrationViewController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
 
        
        let supportedRepresentations = [UTType.rawImage.identifier,
                                        UTType.tiff.identifier,
                                        UTType.bmp.identifier,
                                        UTType.png.identifier,
                                        UTType.jpeg.identifier,
                                        UTType.webP.identifier,
        ]
        for representation in supportedRepresentations {
            if results[0].itemProvider.hasRepresentationConforming(toTypeIdentifier: representation, fileOptions: .init()) {
                print(representation, " repr")
                
                    results[0].itemProvider.loadInPlaceFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: representation) { (originalUrl, inPlace, error) in
                        
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                print(originalUrl, "  ", inPlace)

                                self.addPhotoButton.setImage(UIImage(contentsOfFile: originalUrl!.path), for: .normal)
                            //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
       }
```

}

Thanks

Comment: The `UIImagePickerController` can pick a `webp` image. But cannot multi-choose.

Comment: @蘇哲聖 PHPickerViewController is not a UIImagePickerController. PHPicker is a new API provided by apple in ios 15.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation` to load `webp` image:

```
import PhotosUI
class Coordinator: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
  init(handler: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {self.handler = handler}
  
  let handler: (UIImage) -> Void
  
  func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    for itemProvider in results.map({$0.itemProvider}) {
      if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.webP.identifier) {
        itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.webP.identifier) {data, err in
          if let data = data, let img = UIImage.init(data: data) {
            self.handler(img)
          }
        }
      } else {
        itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {reading, err in
          if let img = reading as? UIImage {
            self.handler(img)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After many experiments I found a solution.
use "loadDataRepresentation" instead of "loadInPlaceFileRepresentation" so you can get data and build an image.

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    
    
    let supportedRepresentations = [UTType.rawImage.identifier,
                                    UTType.tiff.identifier,
                                    UTType.bmp.identifier,
                                    UTType.png.identifier,
                                    UTType.jpeg.identifier,
                                    UTType.webP.identifier,
    ]
    
    for representation in supportedRepresentations {
        if results[0].itemProvider.hasRepresentationConforming(toTypeIdentifier: representation, fileOptions: .init()) {
            
            results[0].itemProvider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: representation) { (data, err) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let img = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.addPhotoButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are loading the image 6 times... that's bad.

Answer (score 1):

Set PHPickerConfiguration to:

```
var config = PHPickerConfiguration(photoLibrary: .shared())
config.preferredAssetRepresentationMode = .current <====
```

Set this configuartion in your PHPickerController:

```
let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
```

and then inside **func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult])** Delegate callback:

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) 

    let provider = results[index].itemProvider
        
    provider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.image", completionHandler: { photoData, error in
        if error == nil, let photoData = photoData, let photo = UIImage(data: photoData){
                
        }else{
                
        }
    })
}
```