# "unsupported file format 'org.webmproject.webp'" while saving CGImage in webp format

Tags: ios, swift, cgimage, photokit

Currently, we are using `PHPickerViewController` + `CGImage` for efficient memory usage consideration - https://christianselig.com/2020/09/phpickerviewcontroller-efficiently/

However, we are getting `"unsupported file format 'org.webmproject.webp'"` error, while trying to save `CGImage` in webp format.

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    guard !results.isEmpty else { return }

    for result in results {
        result.itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.image.identifier) { (url, error) in
            guard let url = url else { return }
            
            let options: [CFString: Any] = [
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true,
                kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: true,
                kCGImageSourceShouldCacheImmediately: true,
                kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: 512
            ]

            guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as NSURL, nil) else { return }

            let image = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as CFDictionary)
            
            //
            // No issue in dealing with UTType.jpeg.identifier and UTType.png.identifier.
            // destUrl is type URL.
            //
            guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(destUrl as CFURL, UTType.webP.identifier, 1, nil) else { return }
            CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image!, nil)
            CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
        }
    }
}
```

We face no issue in saving `CGImage` in `UTType.jpeg.identifier` format and `UTType.png.identifier` format.

May I know how can we save `CGImage` in webp format without issue? Thank you.

Comment: The obviously conclusion is that Core Graphics can't create webp images - it is an unsupported format. Use PNG or JPEG or write your own code to convert a CGImage to webp.

Comment: @Paulw11 But, any idea why there isn't any issue, if we read a webp image file into a CGImage, and save it to png/ jpeg using `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL`, `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` and `CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex`? The only issue is when written CGImage back to webp format...

Comment: The error message says that it isn't supported, so I guess it isn't supported. Maybe reading is but writing isn't?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get WebP images from gallery with PHPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68255880/how-to-get-webp-images-from-gallery-with-phpicker)

Answer (score 0):

`webp` is not supported for **encoding**.

You can use function like this to list supported types:

```
void listImageCodecs(void){
    CFArrayRef mySourceTypes = CGImageSourceCopyTypeIdentifiers();
    CFShow(mySourceTypes);
    CFArrayRef myDestinationTypes = CGImageDestinationCopyTypeIdentifiers();
    CFShow(myDestinationTypes);
}
```

On my system I have such a result:

```
(
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.png",
    "com.compuserve.gif",
    "com.canon.tif-raw-image",
    "com.adobe.raw-image",
    "com.dxo.raw-image",
    "com.canon.cr2-raw-image",
    "com.canon.cr3-raw-image",
    "com.leafamerica.raw-image",
    "com.hasselblad.fff-raw-image",
    "com.hasselblad.3fr-raw-image",
    "com.nikon.raw-image",
    "com.nikon.nrw-raw-image",
    "com.pentax.raw-image",
    "com.samsung.raw-image",
    "com.sony.raw-image",
    "com.sony.sr2-raw-image",
    "com.sony.arw-raw-image",
    "com.epson.raw-image",
    "com.kodak.raw-image",
    "public.tiff",
    "public.jpeg-2000",
    "com.apple.atx",
    "org.khronos.astc",
    "org.khronos.ktx",
    "public.avci",
    "public.heic",
    "public.heics",
    "public.heif",
    "com.canon.crw-raw-image",
    "com.fuji.raw-image",
    "com.panasonic.raw-image",
    "com.panasonic.rw2-raw-image",
    "com.leica.raw-image",
    "com.leica.rwl-raw-image",
    "com.konicaminolta.raw-image",
    "com.olympus.sr-raw-image",
    "com.olympus.or-raw-image",
    "com.olympus.raw-image",
    "com.phaseone.raw-image",
    "com.microsoft.ico",
    "com.microsoft.bmp",
    "com.apple.icns",
    "com.adobe.photoshop-image",
    "com.microsoft.cur",
    "com.truevision.tga-image",
    "com.ilm.openexr-image",
    "org.webmproject.webp",
    "com.sgi.sgi-image",
    "public.radiance",
    "public.pbm",
    "public.mpo-image",
    "public.pvr",
    "com.microsoft.dds",
    "com.apple.pict"
)
(
    "public.jpeg",
    "public.png",
    "com.compuserve.gif",
    "public.tiff",
    "public.jpeg-2000",
    "com.apple.atx",
    "org.khronos.ktx",
    "org.khronos.astc",
    "com.microsoft.dds",
    "public.heic",
    "public.heics",
    "com.microsoft.ico",
    "com.microsoft.bmp",
    "com.apple.icns",
    "com.adobe.photoshop-image",
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "com.truevision.tga-image",
    "com.ilm.openexr-image",
    "public.pbm",
    "public.pvr"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar issue where the new PHPickerViewController failed to import images with **org.webmproject.webp** extension. Although the above question asks why CGImage with UTType.webP.identifier fails to save, for folks who just wants to import an image with **org.webmproject.webp** extension without caring about the output extension here is a simple solution.

```
func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
    
    var images: [UIImage] = []
    var urls: [URL] = []
    let itemProviders = results.map(\.itemProvider)
    
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.lock()
    
    for itemProvider in itemProviders {
        guard let typeIdentifier = itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first else {
            continue
        }

        dispatchGroup.enter()
        
        if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.movie.identifier) {
            itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: typeIdentifier) { url, err in
                
                if let url = url {
                    if let newTempUrl = CacheManager.shared.saveAssetToTempDirectory(url: url) {
                        urls.append(newTempUrl)
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    } else {
                        dispatchGroup.leave()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if typeIdentifier == "org.webmproject.webp" || itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            itemProvider.loadFileRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: typeIdentifier) { url, err in
                
                if let url = url {
                    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                            images.append(image)
                        }
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
        } else {
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }
    
    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        /// You have the images or video urls for use here
        /// images & urls
    }
}
```